# Sharing folders between 2 users

Tags: macos, security, permission, virtualization

I just downloaded a virtual box VM which I will be sharing with my wife. Both my wife and I have accounts on our mac.

I copied the downloaded VM into /Users/Shared/MyNewVM

Then I went into System Preferences -> Sharing and I added /Users/Shared/MyNewVM

and gave "everyone" the "read/write" permissions.

Now, when I go to Finder and go into /Users/Shared/MyNewVM/VM.vbox and double click it, it gives me the following error:

> You do not have permissions to open document "VM.vbox". Contact your
>   computer and network administrator for assistance.

But I gave the permissions ... didn't I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select the folder in Finder and open Get Info (⌘I).
2. Click the padlock in the bottom-right corner of the Get Info window and authenticate.
3. Set up the permissions, then click the gear and select Apply to enclosed items….